# core dump generation using Websphere liberty is failing

Tags: websphere-liberty, coredump

I am trying to generate javadump and core dump for the liberty process, using:

/opt/IBM/wlp/bin/server javadump  --include=system

It is failing giving an error:
Server default dump complete in /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers//The core file created by child process with pid = 22000 was not found. Expected to find core file with name "/var/support/core_kernel-command-.22000"

My core_pattern(/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern) is /var/support/core_%e.%p
I am using java 8.

Comment: Did you look for the core elsewehre? Is that directory writable by the java process?

Comment: @covener: After rebooting the VM it runs ok. But with the first setup it is failing. But I need to make it running after the first install itself. I am unable to figure out what is changing after the system reboot?

Comment: This appears to be a JVM issue in locating a core file with the specified pattern, possibly similar to [IV22692](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV22692).  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.